# Apparent different sizes when attempting to export a particular mysql database

Tags: backup, mysql, size, phpmyadmin, mediawiki

In a quite old-versioned CentOS-Bash "shared server" environment, I ran the following commands:

```
current_date="$(date +%F-%T)"
db_user_name_and_db_name="db-username_db-name"
war="$HOME/public_html" # Web Application Root

mkdir -p "${war}/mediawiki_general_backups"
```

My problem is that If I make a quick export (all tables) of the relevant database from PHPMyAdmin GUI, I get a `.sql` file of **43MBs**.
But, if I export the same database by a CLUI command such as the following, I get a `.sql` file of **23MBs**:

```
mysqldump \
-u "${db_user_name_and_db_name}" \
-p "${db_user_name_and_db_name}" \
> "${war}/mediawiki_general_backups/${db_user_name_and_db_name}-${current_date}.sql"
```

I don't know how to explain this difference; do you?

Comment: Did you actually _look_ at the dumps to try to figure out why they are of different size? Is one compressed? Is one using inserts for each value while the other does bulk inserts?

Comment: I didn't open the files with a text editor fearing of very slow loading and seeing gibberish-like content I wouldn't understand but they were opened very fast and right on start I can see many (well presented) differences in documentation. In the smaller one I can indeed see the term `compessed` appearing lots of times near the starting of the file (in the larger file it is absent); because both files end with `.sql` I didn't imagine one would be compressed. The smaller file has tens of `INSERT` queries while the larger one has hundreds of it which might indicate bulk inserting.

Comment: I assume `mysqldump` as installed by the hosting provider (SiteGround) compresses by default, unlike PHPMyAdmin SQL Dump 4.7.3 that they use as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do quick testing; export a table in PhpMyadmin and with the following command in terminal.

```
mysqldump -u $UserName -p database table > /tmp/table.sql
```

Then, open both SQL files with a text-editor; difference should be recognized immediately:
I recognized lots of comments which is exported from PHPMyAdmin and the way of `INSERT`ing data. For example:

Exported SQL has the following header:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.0.10.20
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Oct 10, 2019 at 03:48 AM
-- Server version: 5.1.73-log
-- PHP Version: 5.3.3

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
```

Dumped SQL has the following header:

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.1.73, for redhat-linux-gnu (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: testing
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.1.73-log

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
```

Comment: Indeed, by Kusalananda's comment I did that and noted the difference; I guess I should just relay on `mysqldump` as is; now I now that internal-compressing might be utilized without me knowing it (for about 23 years I knew archives should have external indication such as a `tar` or `zip` or `rar` file extension but today I learned this is not necessary...